# Why MKL-FFTW3 library could not be called in ABAQUS subroutine

Tags: fortran, linker-errors, fftw, intel-mkl, abaqus

I found a way to call MKL library in ABAQUS subroutine in https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-math-kernel-library/topic/720340. 
I followed the method to add

```
compile_fortran=[...'/Qmkl:sequential'...]
```

It works well with normal MKL libraries such as degsv and so on. But when I
want to call MKL-FFTW3 library, the ABAQUS shows errors and I check the log file, the errors as below

```
Intel(R) Visual Fortran Intel(R) 64 Compiler for applications running on 
Intel(R) 64, Version 19.0.1.144 Build 20181018
Copyright (C) 1985-2018 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.

End Compiling Abaqus/Standard User Subroutines
Begin Linking Abaqus/Standard User Subroutines
building library object standardU.lib and object standardU.exp
fft_elastic_subroutine.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol dfftw_plan_dft_3d，referenced in function fft3.R
fft_elastic_subroutine.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol dfftw_execute_dft，referenced in function fft3.R
fft_elastic_subroutine.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol dfftw_destroy_plan，referenced in function fft3.R
standardU.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved external symbols
Abaqus Error: Problem during linking - Abaqus/Standard User Subroutines.
This error may be due to a mismatch in the Abaqus user subroutine arguments.
These arguments sometimes change from release to release, so user subroutines used with a previous release of Abaqus 
may need to be adjusted.
```

I used Visual Studio 2017, Intel Visual Fortran 2019, ABAQUS 2019.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

All of these FFTW3 interfaces are integrated into Intel MKL. They are defined in mkl_intel_ilp64.lib, mkl_intel_ilp64_dll.lib mkl_intel_lp64.lib, mkl_intel_lp64_dll.lib and mkl_rt.lib of  Intel® 64 architecture.

You may try to manually link with MKL by following the MKL Linker Adviser tips.